# How to find the time an attribute was added to a version in Clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I'm trying to figure out how long on average I take to review files at work. The way our review system works, someone checks a new version in and applies a Reviewer attribute to the file with the name of the reviewer. Then after the reviewer finishes the review, they apply an **Approved attribute** with the value **"yes"** or **"no"**.

So to find the time it takes for me to review something, I need to find the difference in creation time of the two attributes. Is there a way to find these creation times in clearcase?

I can definitely get the time the version itself was created using cleartool describe, but I didn't see a way to do it for the attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute creation events are "minor" events what will eventually get scrubbed away (The default is 7 days)...

While they are present, you can find them using cleartool lshist -minor {element name}

Comment: Fortunately for me my project seems to have substantially increased the time limit, so following your suggestion I got data for over 60 reviews. Thanks!